# How to build Basic JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, function

I starting to get into using JavaScript more and more these days, although I'm still learning. Having said that, I'd like to check that I'm following what's considered "best practice" when it comes to constructing basic functions.

When I look at other JavaSCript code I often people construct functions in different ways. Of course, it depends on the context of the function.

Out of the following 4 example functions, which will perform the best? What is considered best practice?

I often use a mixture of the first 3 function layouts, while sometimes I use the fourth one for really large heavy stuff.

I've just used a basic click function as an example, but I'd like a broader answer of when to use each of these function syntaxes and why.

1.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('#myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
// do something 
// all future variables are stored locally within the click function
}
```

2.

```
document.getElementById('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', function () {
// do something 
// all future variables are stored locally within the click function
}
```

3.

```
function doSomething() {
// do something 
// all future variables are stored locally within the click function
}

document.getElementById('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', function () {
doSomething();
}
```

4.

```
function doSomething() {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('#myDiv');

   myDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
   // do something 
   // all future variables are stored locally within the click function
   }
 }

new doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 1 and 2 do "the same". Its only a matter of taste and preferences. In the first case you are saving (think in something like "relabel") a reference to the object in "myDiv", in the other case you are calling it directly... For the compiler it will be the same.

With example 3 you are creating a function that calls a function, but because JavaScript is a functional language thats not necesary, you could just pass the function to the other function... Like this:

*Example 3.1:*

```
var doSomething = function() {
// do something 
// all future variables are stored locally within the click function
};    
document.getElementById('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

Yep, addEventListener is a function that receives a function in the second argument :) .

And with example 4 you are doing something different. When you call "new doSomething()" you are instantiating a new object. ¿But why it works? Well, Javascript will run the code inside your function/object, and thats why it works.
But you actually are instantiating a new object (but you don't save it anywhere, so it will be garbage collected... the object, not the things that you do inside of it, because them are in the scope of the div).

I find all examples correct, but I don't like the 4. At least in this case it could be simpler to just call "doSomething()", without the "new".

Comment: How would I call a nested function within a function? for example var doSomething = function() { function doSemethingelse() {} }

Comment: The nested function should be associated with a field of the object/prototipe (in Javascript the prototipe is like the class definition in other languages). Later it can be called with "doSomething.theFunctionField(args);"
Here is explained better: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 1):

1. A good idea if you're going to reuse myDiv more than once since it caches the selector
2. #1's counterpart, if you're not going to select #myDiv again, use this one
3. If you're going to call that function multiple times, ok
4. I'd say only use that when you want the click event to be used at a certain time, a simple function declaration and execution right after has no purpose